# Parent folder affected by child folder htaccess

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

use xampp in windows and there's a subfolder called wordpress.
there's a .htaccess file located in the wordpress folder with content like below:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
# RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/$2 [L]
# RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ C:/xampp/htdocs/wordpress/$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]


# END WordPress
```

All the other folders, and .html .php files in the parent folder are not accessible.
And the screen shows "Establish to database error". which means that I guess all the connection has been redirected to wordpress folder.

What can I do to let other folders and html access become normal?

Comment: Is this in the `/wordpress/` folder?  If so why has the `RewriteBase /wordpress/` been commented out and replaced by the wrong thing?

Comment: Establish to database error usually means that the database configuration settings in wp-config.php do not correspond to an existing database

Comment: Do you have another `.htaccess` file in the root? A `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory won't affect the parent directory unless mod_rewrite inheritance has been enabled (further up the directory tree).